# Discord.py make discord bot react to message with several emotes

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py, response

I know how to make a bot react to a message, but I am stuck with my project and I'm just running constantly into troubles. I want to do a command with the syntax `-react [message ID] [emote1] [emote2] [emote 3] [emote ...]` that reacts to the message belonging to the ID with the emotes I put after the ID.

I know how to make the bot react with the same emotes to always the same message, and tried to make it react to other messages with the code:

```py
@client.command()
async def react(ctx, ID):
    emotes = ['❤️', '']
    msg = message.fetch_message(ID)
    for emote in emotes:
        await ctx.msg.add_reaction(emoji=emote)
```

but this always puts out `NameError: name 'message' is not defined` in `msg = message.fetch_message(ID)`, and additionally I have not the slightest idea how to make it work with own chosen emotes.

So, my main problems are:

1. How can I make the bot react to specific messages? (Solved)
2. How can I make it using own specified emotes?

Update: First problem solved, I simply needed to add

```
message_id = ID
    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(message_id)
```

but I'm still stuck with making it react with user given emotes, not hard-coded ones.

Comment: Think about it: where is `message` defined? Additionally, if you already had the message why would you be calling `fetch_message` from that message? Also it is `ctx.message` not `ctx.msg`, if you want to call `add_reaction` from your variable `msg`, you would just use `msg`, not `ctx.msg`.

Comment: I managed to get the bot react to work on messages from the ID I gave with simply adding 
`message_id = ID
    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(message_id)`
but I'm still stuck with making it react with user given emotes, not hard-coded ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You didn't define `message` variable, that's why it's throwing that error.
2. The `ID` arg is a string, ids must be integers
3. `ctx` doesn't have the attribute `msg` it's `message`

Also to implement the emojis you can simply pass them as a tuple and go through them using a for loop.

```py
@client.command()
async def react(ctx, ID: int, *emojis):
    message = ctx.fetch_message(ID)

    for emoji in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        # Or if you want to add the reactions to the message which invoked the command
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji)
```